# Use Docker to load Image with Dependencies from Private Registry

Tags: image, docker, registry, private, nexus

Our company created an image based on NGINX and uploaded this to a private registry (Nexus OSS). E.g.:

```
FROM nginx:1.14-alpine
COPY ./config/api-gateway.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The image is then pulled from other machines in the network like this

```
docker run my_private_registry/my-api-gateway:latest
```

Looking at the size of the image my-api-gateway (17MB), it seems that it does not contain the base nginx image (33.2MB) which is then pulled.

My question is: Where is this base image pulled from? Does docker use the private registry as proxy or will it contact the public dockerhub?

If it is pulled from dockerhub; how can I tell docker to load this image with all dependencies from our private registry?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use private hosts, you need to specify your remote host:

```
docker login here.com
```

then you can pull you private images:

```
docker pull myrepo.com/myShip:v21
```